# UDP traffic through Socks

Tags: linux, tcp, redirection, udp, socks

How to send all traffic through the socks if it doesn't support UDP filtering directly. For example DNS traffic I can redirect on Socks using the 'DNS Socks Proxy' using the TCP Protocol. Is it possible to do something similar with the rest of the traffic except DNS?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer.  No you can't.

SOCKS5 supports UDP Association, where you can get the SOCKS server to relay UDP data between a client and another endpoint.  There are numerous problems with the design of this however (it reduces payload by adding another layer on top of UDP for the packets between the client and SOCKS server).

So not many SOCKS5 servers support it (ours does).

But there's no way via a SOCKS server to convert TCP to UDP.  If the SOCKS server doesn't support UDP Associate, then you won't get UDP through it.  DNS is only working because DNS also supports TCP.

Comment: What is your server?

Comment: Our server is WinGate